# Branding the looks of a sharepoint 2010 survey

Tags: sharepoint-designer, survey-list

I came across the following article which was very good as a starter to branding surveys: [SharePoint Kings](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/08/creating-and-working-with-survey-in_7080.html). However I don't think that this is a very neat approach of how to brand a survey.  Is there another way to do same things as described in the article by means of an application page or webpart??

Also tried with sharepoint designer to create a new display form but all i saw was the following:
[image]
so couldn't figure out how to edit each question.

I know that surveys are lists but cannot picture in my mind how I can customize the page to show in a branded way.

Answer (score 2):

If you add "tokens" to your survey questions, you can use javascript to convert them into tags, and then use css to render the styles. For example, #b#somestyle#/b#  and javascript can search the question and replace the tokens with **somestyle** after the page has been loaded.

You can put the replacement routine in a function, and call it with

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("someFunction");
```

which will cause it to load after sharepoint has built and displayed the page.

see here for info on the replacement script: http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/08/creating-and-working-with-survey-in_7080.html

Another option would be to edit `NewForm.aspx`, `EditForm.aspx`, etc. in InfoPath Designer - but that is only good if you are using Sharepoint Enterprise.

Answer (score -1):

You can do some branding changes by creating a custom survey list definition. This blog post describes how you can create the list definition and how you can modify NewForm and EditForm: [Hide save and close buton in survey](http://lillebuenitblog.blogspot.no/2014/04/sharepoint-2010-surveys-hide-save-and.html)

The modification here is to remove the save and close button, but you can add your own branding instead. The DispForm.aspx can be customized the same way.

Comment: Please do not just link to your private blog, instead add more details to your answer and use the blog link as merely a reference.