# Survey Section/Page heading

Tags: survey-list

I have a survey spread onto numerous pages. I would like to add a heading at the start of each page of the survey. Is this possible? How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was using JQuery/JavaScript. Basically using JavaScript I look to see if the first question on a section was present and depending on the question I find I would write the section heading to a  tag. I did a search like you and could not find anything so that is what I came up with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the same but my <h1> tag was being rendered as text and not markup :(

Answer (score 0):

That happen to me to. This is why I used the text of the first question in the section to search for. If found, then add appropriate heading.

Answer (score 0):

See this post about how to brand a sharepoint survey.

[Branding the looks of a sharepoint 2010 survey](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25377/branding-the-looks-of-a-sharepoint-2010-survey/43146#43146)

Following the answer there, if you add a token like `#sectiontitle#My Section Title#/sectiontitle#` to the text of each question that comes first in a section, you can use javascript to replace this with your own html.